# File name change script not working in second run of loop

Tags: bash

This code is meant to search a set of folders containing files with name format DD-MM-YYYY and renames them as YYYY-MM-DD. However, while this loop works fine on the first iteration, it doesn't interpret the regular expression in the second run.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
WORKING_DIRS=( "/directory1" "/directory2" )
for WORKING_DIR in ${WORKING_DIRS[@]}
do
echo "WORKING DIRECTORY : $WORKING_DIR"
echo "--------------------------------------------------------"
for entry in "$WORKING_DIR"/[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].doc
do
    IFS='/'
    read -r -a array <<< "$entry"
    file_name="${array[${#array[@]}-1]}"
    echo "$file_name"
    IFS='.'
    read -r -a file <<< "$file_name"
    echo "OLD DATE: $file"
    IFS='-'
    read -r -a file_split <<< "${file[0]}"
    day=${file_split[0]}
    month=${file_split[1]}
    year=${file_split[2]}
    new_date="$year-$month-$day"
    echo "NEW DATE : $new_date"
    mv "$WORKING_DIR"/"$file_name" "$WORKING_DIR"/"$new_date".doc
done
done
```

Comment: @Inian Sorry, I upvoted it but didn't have enough rep at the time for it to register. Just upvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the `IFS` value modification in the body of the loop multiple times. Once you modify it the rest of the `word-splitting`  is done by the modified `IFS` which does not allow your glob pattern to expand.

You can avoid it by passing the value to the `read` command locally and *not* modifying it globally, which should solve your problem.

```
IFS='/' read -r -a array <<< "$entry"
IFS='.' read -r -a file <<< "$file_name"
IFS='-' read -r -a file_split <<< "${file[0]}"
```

---

Also in general in looping over a `glob` pattern it is always to check the file existence before processing the file, to avoid ugly errors

```
for entry in "$WORKING_DIR"/[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].doc
do
    [ -e "$entry" ] || continue

    # rest of the code following
```

(and)

Double-quoting the array expansion as below to avoid getting the individual elements split again. Not doing so, will result in each entry of the array subject to word-splitting by `IFS`

```
for WORKING_DIR in "${WORKING_DIRS[@]}"; do
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why your script does not work but without an example content of your directories, it is difficult to reproduce the error. Anyway, it looks a bit complicated for a rather simple task. You could simplify, e.g. by using the `=~` operator of the conditional expressions. Example:

```
for n in "$WORKING_DIR"/*.doc; do
  if [[ $n =~ (.*\/)([0-9][0-9])(-[0-9][0-9]-)([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])\.doc ]]; then
    mv $n ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[4]}${BASH_REMATCH[3]}${BASH_REMATCH[2]}.doc
  fi
done
```